# credential failed: First argument "token" must be a valid string or a valid object

Tags: reactjs, firebase, github, karma-runner, karma-mocha

Why i get the following errors, when i try to run my test:

**Test with todos in firebase**

> × "before each" hook for "Should Toggle Todo and dispatch UPDATE_TODO
>   acti
>           Chrome 61.0.3163 (Windows 10 0.0.0)
>
> ```
>   credential failed: First argument "token" must be a valid string or a valid object
> ```

---

> × "after each" hook for "Should Toggle Todo and dispatch UPDATE_TODO
>   actio
>           Chrome 61.0.3163 (Windows 10 0.0.0)
>
> ```
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined
>       at Context.eval (eval at <anonymous> (app/tests/actions/actions.test.j
> ```

---

```
describe('Test with todos in firebase',() => {
    var testTodoRef;
    var uid;
    var todosRef;

    beforeEach((done) => {
      var credential = firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider.credential(process.env.GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN);
      console.log('XXXX',credential);
      firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential).then((user) => {
        uid = user.uid;
        todosRef = firebaseRef.child(`users/${uid}/todos`);

        return todosRef.remove();
      }).then(() => {
        testTodoRef = todosRef.push();

        return testTodoRef.set({
          text: 'Something to do',
          completed: false,
          createdAt: 23453453
        })
      })
      .then(() => done())
      .catch(done);
    });

    afterEach((done) => {
      todosRef.remove().then(() => done());
    });
```